# Chrome ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: google-chrome

Getting in for some time on google pages. I.e. can't search anything in google, google callendar doesn't load, etc.

Found some talk about it in the net. Generally temporary solution seems to be turning off **quic** protocol.

But how to do this?

Comment: BTW. It seems it broke after installing http://dexpot.de/ Before that I've never seen such behaviour in chrome.

Comment: I've never installed dexpot.de, but started seeing this recently quite often.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

chrome://flags/

And search for quic on the page. Disabling it resolved my issue.
Hope this helps someone.